# reactjs cant use Unity class? It doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I wanna use Unity.call() function
it was work in the valina javascript.
but in react, It isn't work. can't find unity class
what should I do?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: const callUnity = () => {
    Unity.call('anchor');
  };

just it. very simple

Comment: Are you importing the library, provide some code or be a bit more specific about the error that you are getting